# Exception not getting caught with Guava Cache?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Setup:

```
CacheLoader<String, Set<String>> loader = new CacheLoader<>() {
    public Set<String> load(String s) {
        return privateFunction(s);
    }
};

this.cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(1000).expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build(loader);
```

Implementation:

```
public Set<String> getTeamIdsForEmployee(String employeeAlias) {
        try {
            return this.cache.get(employeeAlias);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // If I don't catch ExecutionException, it complains.
            throw new DependencyException(
                    "message",
                    e);
        }
    }
```

Test:

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = MyCustomException.class)
    public void testGetTeamIdsForEmployeeCacheException() {
        doThrow(new ExecutionException("Test exception", new Exception()))
                .when(thing).privateFunction(eq("SAMPLE"));

        myClass.callCache("SAMPLE");
    }
```

Test fails with:

```
   [testng] Expected exception of type class com.amazon.ampspermissionsservice.exceptions.DependencyException but got org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
   [testng] Checked exception is invalid for this method!
   [testng] Invalid: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
```

How on earth is it not catching the *exact* exception I'm specifying?

I tried catching Throwable and it still won't catch?

Comment: Can you post your `privateFunction` code ? The error comes from it. `privateFunction` does not mention that it can throws `ExecutionException` but it's mandatory because `ExecutionException` is a checked exception (does not inherit from `RuntimeException`).

Comment: The Guava cache loader itself is actually what's threatening to throw `ExecutionException`. `privateFunction` just calls a mocked function, which I have mocked to throw ExecutionException in the test (`doThrow`) to simulate the same failure. Would an uncaught exception in `privateFunction` not bubble up? @JuniorDussouillez

Comment: Ok I looked a bit inside the Guava cache objects, and the `ExecutionException` is thrown in the `get` method, not in the loader. So if you to test that when the get fails you go in the `catch(ExecutionException)` block, you need to mock the cache `get` method, not the function that generates your values. So it would be something like `doThrow(ExecutionException.class).when(myInstance.cache).get(...)`